# Grails downgrade to 1.3.7 from 1.4.0 and broke jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, grails-plugin

I'm not sure why this happened, but when I downgrade grails from 1.4.0 to 1.3.7 it causes this to my jquery plugin when I `grails run-app`

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jquery.JQueryConfig
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jquery.JQueryConfig
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:723)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:573)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:519)
    at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
    at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jquery.JQueryConfig
    at JqueryGrailsPlugin$_closure1.class$(JqueryGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at JqueryGrailsPlugin$_closure1.$get$$class$org$codehaus$groovy$grails$plugins$jquery$JQueryConfig(JqueryGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at JqueryGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(JqueryGrailsPlugin.groovy:53)
    at JqueryGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(JqueryGrailsPlugin.groovy)
```

I have to `grails clean` every time before I can `grails run-app` please help.

Comment: by the way, I have put Grails 1.4 in production without problems, what did you face that was not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried deleting your jquery plugin from ~/.grails/yourproject/plugins and forcing a reinstall?

Also, check application.properties to see if the version did not downgrade properly, I've heard rumours of plugins not downgrading properly when you downgrade grails version (has to do with dependency chains or something like that iirc). If your jquery plugin is tagged with M1 that is probably it.

Comment: did all of that, but still got that error. I'll see if upgrading to 2.0 solve that problem. The reason that I downgrade from 1.3.7 is because 1.4 is quite flaky.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the changes done in the conf/jquery config file ?

http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery

I suspect your configuration is specifically requiring some code that is not available anymore.

Search for:
    JQueryConfig
in your configuration folder.

Comment: I guess the problem is not a problem anymore, becuase grails 2.0 uses jQuery as a default javascript library.

Comment: Yes indeed. For the sake of this question, did you have to change something to your configuration ?